# Send json string as httpBody data using objective c

Tags: objective-c, json, ios7

I have been trying to send json string converted to nsdata to http body part.
but i always find that correct value is never passed on to

**What i want on server :**

```
{"request":"{\"Files\":[{'FileName':'11111111','FileType':'test'}]}"}
```

**What i receive on server :**

```
{"request":{"Files":[{"FileName":"test.html","FileType":"test"}]}}
```

**Can anybody suggest me what am i doing wrong :**

**I tried following ways :**

**Way  : 1**

```
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestDict1 options:0 error:nil];

NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[jsonData bytes] length:[jsonData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

**Way  : 2**

```
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestDict1 options:0 error:nil];

[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
```

Crust is i want to send nsdata format of json tring but i cant get perfect value on the server.
Can anybody suggest me a possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestDict1 options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setHTTPBody:jsonString];
```

Comment: what is the NSLog for requestDict1?

Comment: requestDict1 :: {
    request =     {
        Files =         (
                        {
                FileName = "test.html";
                FileType = test;
            }
        );
    };
}